# Nested IIF/SWITCH in Report Builder: Error BC30201 Expression Expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I'm doing some Background Colour formatting in Report Builder 3, but I'm having difficulty with this expression. Is it too complicated for the report to run, or am I missing something?

Pseudo Code - If Marks is Null (True), Background Colour is White, else if Coursecode is L1 English (number), Format Grades (Switch 1) else format grades (Switch 2).

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Marks.Value), 
    "White",
    IIF(Fields!CourseCode.Value = '50089109',
        SWITCH(
            Fields!Marks.Value > 57, "YellowGreen",
            Fields!Marks.Value >= 48 AND Fields!Marks.Value <= 57 , "Orange",
            Fields!Marks.Value < 48, "Firebrick"
        )
        ,
        SWITCH(
            Fields!Marks.Value > 61, "YellowGreen",
            Fields!Marks.Value >= 52 AND Fields!Marks.Value <= 61 , "Orange",
            Fields!Marks.Value < 52, "Firebrick"
        )
    )
)
```

This was my other approach for the same problem - starting by evaluating if the course code is true, then applying formatting based on that:

```
=IIF(Fields!CourseCode.Value = '50089109',
    IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Marks.Value), "White",
    SWITCH(
        Fields!Marks.Value > 57, "YellowGreen",
        Fields!Marks.Value >= 48 AND Fields!Marks.Value <= 57 , "Orange",
        Fields!Marks.Value < 48, "Firebrick"
        )
    ),
    IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Marks.Value), "White", 
    SWITCH(
        Fields!Marks.Value > 61, "YellowGreen",
        Fields!Marks.Value >= 52 AND Fields!Marks.Value <= 61 , "Orange",
        Fields!Marks.Value < 52, "Firebrick"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you getting errors or are you getting the incorrect background colours? BTW: Instead of "White" use `Nothing` which is the default if no background color has been set.

Comment: Getting `Error BC30201 Expression Expected` - good tip for the BG colour - thansk!

Comment: You're using single quotes around '50089109', which is not allowed. If you use double-quotes, that should work. Single quotes in an SSRS expression indicates a comment.

Comment: You're quite right - well spotted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really see much wrong with your expression so it might be that some values are not being trapped. For testing purposes I would set a background color other than white so you can see if the first condition is being met. You can also clean up the SWITCH statements a little.

So, for testing purposes I would use the following expression

**Test Version**

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Marks.Value), 
    "LimeGreen",
    IIF(Fields!CourseCode.Value = "50089109",
        SWITCH(
            Fields!Marks.Value > 57, "YellowGreen",
            Fields!Marks.Value >= 48, "Orange",
            Fields!Marks.Value < 48, "Firebrick",
            True, "HotPink"
        )
        ,
        SWITCH(
            Fields!Marks.Value > 61, "YellowGreen",
            Fields!Marks.Value >= 52, "Orange",
            Fields!Marks.Value < 52, "Firebrick",
            True, "HotPink"
        )
    )
)
```

Anything trapped by the True part of the IIF will be LimeGreen and anything that is on the false part, but does not match any of the switch statements will be pink. You'll also notice that I have removed part of the middle expressions in the switch statement. These are not required as switch statements stop when the first true condition is met. You'll see that in the 'production' version below, we can remove even more.

We have also added a final switch expression, `true`. As Switch stops at the first true expression the `true` in our new expression acts like an `else`

Once you have fixed any issues, the production version would look like this.

**Production Version**

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Marks.Value), 
    Nothing,
    IIF(Fields!CourseCode.Value = "50089109",
        SWITCH(
            Fields!Marks.Value > 57, "YellowGreen",
            Fields!Marks.Value >= 48, "Orange",
            True, "Firebrick"
        )
        ,
        SWITCH(
            Fields!Marks.Value > 61, "YellowGreen",
            Fields!Marks.Value >= 52, "Orange",
            True, "Firebrick"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, worked great. Also missed the fact I single-quoted the CourseCode which didn't help.